# Execute script based on change to Mysql Records count

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How do I execute a script based on a change to the total count of records in a mysql table. `div1` echoes the amount of records in a table just fine. Using the .load ajax request, the div is constantly refreshed every 0,5 second so it'll always know how many records there are almost real-time.

```
 <div class="div1"> 
            <?php $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);   
            echo "table has $row_cnt records" ; ?>                  
 </div>

 <script>
    function refreshdiv(){
        $('.div1').load('backendform.php',function () {
             $(this).unwrap();
        });
    }
    refreshdiv();
    setInterval(function(){
        refreshdiv();
    }, 500);
</script>
```

Here I'm trying to figure out how to call a JS function when the count has changed within the last minute (or second, doesn't matter). So if $row_cnt has for example changed from outputting 5 to 6, how do I trigger the execution for this statement?

```
<?php
//if record was added in last minute
if($row_cnt...)
echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'notification();',
     '</script>'
;?>
<script>
```

I suppose what also could work is if I could tell if a record has been added to the Mysql table within the last few seconds. Each record has a timestamp. But I don't even know if this can be done because I found no similar questions on SO.

Comment: you maylooking for http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/ or triggers.

Comment: definitely not a job for javascript. Probably not a job for a php web page. Your better options are mysql events and a cron job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set data for `#div1` like `data-row`

```
<?php $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows( $result ); ?>
<div class="div1" data-row="<?php echo $row_cnt ?>">
    <?php echo "table has $row_cnt records"; ?>
</div>
```

put `notification` function in `setInterval` and use `#div1` `data-row` to compare:

```
<script>
    function refreshdiv() {
        $('.div1').load('backendform.php', function () {
            $(this).unwrap();
        });
    }
    refreshdiv();
    function notification() {
        var row = $('.div1').attr('data-row');
        if (row == 2) {
            //do something
        }
        else{
            //do something
        }
    }
    setInterval(function () {
        refreshdiv();
        notification();
    }, 500);
</script>
```

Comment: That executes a script when the row is identical to a specific number. Eg, if the row count is 5, the if statement executes when `(row == 5)`, but how do I execute the if statement if the row number has changed, no matter to what number?

Comment: you can store the first value of row to a variable and compare

Comment: Could you edit your question to account for that? Because I don't know why it's not working for me. Also, your code works for when the row count is the same as a specific number, but when I remove records in the table to bring the row count down to the specific number, it alerts only when the page has reloaded, that's while the div1 has already refreshed before that happens and outputs the right row count.

Comment: the problem is `notification ` run before `refreshdiv ` completely finish load the `div1`, hmm..